# different unique elements in array

Tags: c, arrays

I try to write code for counting number of different unique elements in the given array but I get undesired output.`{ 2, 7, 5, 8, 9, 5, 7, 5, 5, 3}`this is the given array elements.Different unique values are `{ 2, 8, 9, 3}` it means there are 4. But my program returns 6: { 2, 5, 8, 9, 7, 3}

here is my code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>


int unique(int *arr, int n)
{
     int u = 1;

     for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
     {
        int is_u = 1;
        for (int j = 0; is_u && j < i; ++j)
        {
             if (arr[j] == arr[i]) is_u = 0;
        }
        if (is_u) ++u;
     }
     return u;
}


int main(void) {
    int arr[] = { 2, 7, 5, 8, 9, 5, 7, 5, 5, 3};
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    printf("%d", unique(arr, n));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sort the array (in place if it's okay to modify it) and it's easy to find duplicates and remove them.

Comment: Code seems to be working as designed - there are 6 different numbers in your array

Comment: As for your problem, I recommend that you [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: is your problem solve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to check the entire array (currently your inner loop goes only up to `i`).

```
    for (int j = 0; is_u && j < n; ++j)
    {
         /* i != j to avoid comparing an element with itself. */
         if (i != j && arr[j] == arr[i]) is_u = 0;
    }
```

Yours is obviously an O(n*n) algorithm. You could sort and check consequent elements to do the same in O(n log n).

If you could use additional O(n) memory to use an auxiliary array to as a "counter", then it could be done in O(n) time complexity as well.

Comment: If you use an array as counter then it would be `O(max_element)`. Probably an hash map would be a better choice if the values of the array are not themselves `O(n)`

Answer (score 1):

This code give you the unique number's count from the Array

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int unique(int *arr, int n)
{
     int u = 0;

     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
     {
        int is_u = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            //printf("%d,%d\n", arr[i], arr[j]);
             if (arr[i] == arr[j] && i != j){ 
                 //printf("match %d\n", arr[i]);
                 is_u = 0; break;
             }
        }
        if (is_u) ++u;

        //printf("u %u \n",u);
     }
     return u;
}


int main(void) {
    int arr[] = { 2, 7, 5, 8, 9, 5, 7, 5, 5, 3};
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    printf("%d", unique(arr, n));
    return 0;
}
```

Two nested for loop using in this code, 
the first for loop hold an array index. second for loop compare that index value to all array value if the same value not found in the array (except the same index) then increment in 'u'.

Answer (score 1):

- `u` should not be initialized to 1. You don't know if there are duplicates yet.

This line

```
int u = 1;
```

Should be

```
int u = 0;
```

---

- Array's are 0 based.

This line

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
```

Should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) // NOTE i = 0 vs i = 1
```

---

- Don't limit to i. You want to scan the entire array to find a duplicate

This line

```
for (int j = 0; is_u && j < i; ++j)
```

Should be

```
for (int j = 0; is_u && j < n; ++j) // NOTE j < n vs j < i
```

---

- You need to ignore the current index when doing the secondary scan. Otherwise all elements would be considered duplicates.

This line

```
if (arr[j] == arr[i]) is_u = 0;
```

Should be

```
if (j != i && arr[j] == arr[i]) is_u = 0; // NOTE added condition of j != i
```